# AngularJS $resource management

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find a clean way to manage my `$resource` models in my application.  I have some RESTful endpoints for a `template` model:

```
GET /api/templates/      //query all template
GET /api/template/:id    // get single template by id
PUT /api/template/       // create a new template
PATCH /api/template/:id  // update a template
DELETE /api/template/:id // delete a template

var TemplateResource = $resource('/api/templates/:templateId', {templateId:'@id'}, {
                'create':{method:'PUT'}
            })
```

I can simply run

```
var templates = TemplateResource.query(function(){
      console.log(templates) // an array of template models
}
```

Once I have the list in memory, I use an Angular service to keep the list in state and consecutive calls just return the list rather then making the call again.

Now my question is regarding how to manage a single `template`. If the user goes to the "Edit Template" view, then saves the template I run `template.$save()` to run a POST on the template. The problem is that this template is seperate from the list that was pulled in from the `query`, so the list doesn't get updated in the UI.

Should I stem all my single `template` requests from my list of `template`s? (meaning I never actually call GET /api/template/:id, instead I just always find the template in the list)

OR

Should I just continue to run individual calls on the `template`, and when the POST request comes back, I just "update" the current list of `template`s with the updated model.

Let me know if I should provide more info about something

Comment: Both options are viable (basing everything off of the root list, or getting a new list any time something changes.) One uses less bandwidth, the other is less likely to become out of date when multiple people are using the application at the same time.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about when multiple people are on the site at once. Typically its just 1 user, but as we scale it could be more. Maybe I am overcomplicating things by trying to "cache" items in the Angular Service. I think I should just pull everything new each time the controller needs it.